# Integrating a Kaplan-Meier estimator in R

Tags: r, integration

I write the following code to calculate the Kaplan-Meier estimator in R.

```
library(survival) 
data(veteran)
attach(veteran)

library(Rfast)

KM <- function(u){
t <- sort_unique(u)
Y <- sapply(t, function(x) sum(u>=x))
d <- sapply(t, function(x) sum(u==x & status == 1))
cumprod(1-d/Y)
}

KM(time) # Kaplan-Meier estimates value
```

But, I am getting the wrong results while I run the following code for estimating the integral [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qqips.png)

`integrate(Vectorize(KM),10,999)`

It would be a great help if somebody can help me writing an R code for estimating the integral [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qqips.png) in R.

Comment: what is the correct result as expected of integral? I suspect you did not define `KM` for `Kaplan-Meier estimator` correctly.

Comment: The code for Kaplan-Meier estimator works perfectly fine. But the problem is with writing the code for the integral [1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qqips.png, where the integrand is the Kaplan-Meier estimator.

Comment: I got `-125603 with absolute error < 1.4e-09` when running `integrate(Vectorize(KM),10,999)`. What should be the correct result?

Comment: The answer is wrong. The area under the curve can not be negative. In fact, I have got the answer. Please check the following link [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/450773/integrate-kaplan-meier-estimator-quickly-in-r)